# Path Animation into a Button

Tags: wpf, animation, events, button, path

I have a button with a Path, What I want is that when I make a click over the button the path moves to the rigth side; I've added the style and the trigger to the button, but it doesn't work. I've tried to add the trigger to the ControlTemplate but it doesn't let me

If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

This is my code:

```
<Button x:Name="btnEnviarCorreo" Height="50" Width="100" Padding="5"  Content="Enviar Correo" Margin="2,2" >
<Button.Style>
<Style TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./#Segoe UI" />
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
<Grid>
<Path x:Name="PathIcon" Width="15" Height="25" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#E59400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,0,0,0" Data="F1M30.0833,22.1667L50.6665,37.6043 50.6665,38.7918 30.0833,53.8333 30.0833,22.1667z"/>                                                          <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</Grid>                                 
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
<Setter TargetName="PathIcon" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Trigger>                                  
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>                             
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
<EventTrigger.Actions>
<BeginStoryboard>
<Storyboard>
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PathIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="200" />
</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>                
</Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code somewhere inside `ControlTemplate.Triggers` block:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation From="17,0,0,0" To="100, 0, 0, 0" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="PathIcon"/> 
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
```

It's not perfect, you should work out to set some details on your own. I use animation for Margin within an `EventTrigger`. You can try to make some other experiments :D

Comment: Thank so much, that helps me a lot. I really appreciate your help